# Input too big for array

Tags: c, string

I have a small question that I was just wondering about.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char n_string[5];

    printf("Please enter your first name: ");
    scanf("%s", n_string);
    printf("\nYour name is: %s", n_string);

    return 0;
}
```

On the 5th line I declare a string of 4 letters. Now this means I will only be able to hold 4 characters in that string, correct?
If I execute my program and write the name: Alexander, I get the output:

```
Your name is Alexander.
```

My question is, how come I could put a string of 9 characters into an array that holds 4?

Comment: This is **undefined behaviour**. On your machine/compiler you could do this because you've compiler laid out stack variables in a particular way. Change machine/compiler/compiler options/add variables and you you might be getting a crash, or printout of a garbage values, or anything else.

Comment: I did not know this previously, interesting!

Comment: Note: Code could use `scanf("%4s", n_string);` (or other functions) to prevent saving too much in `n_string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overwriting a part of your program's stack by doing that, which is generally a very bad thing. In this case, you got lucky, but if you write further you will almost certainly get a `segfault`, when `main` tries to return.

Malicious actors will use this as a buffer overflow attack, to overwrite a function's return address.

If your question is "Why does C allow me to do this?", the answer is that `C` does not do bounds checking on arrays. It treats arrays (more or less) as a pointer to an address in memory, and `scanf` is more than happy to write to the memory location without worrying about what it actually represents.

Answer (score 3):

You allocated 5 bytes, but since your CPU probably requires 16-byte alignment, the compiler probably allocated 16 bytes. Try this :

```
char n_string[5];
volatile int some_int;

some_int= 0;
sscanf(..);

printf("%s %d\n", n_string, some_int);
```

Is `some_int` still 0? Writing into `n_string` may have caused a buffer overflow and written bad data to `some_int`. Of course your compiler probably knows that some_int will stay a zero, so we declare it like `volatile int some_int;` to stop it from optimizing.

Answer (score 2):

You reserve memory for 4 letters and the terminating zero. You write nine letters and a zero to it. You overstepped your bounds by 5 bytes. Those 5 bytes belonged to someone else, you just trashed his memory.

The most likely candidate for this is variables that are close. Test this, although not guaranteed, chances are you will see what happens with your remaining bytes: they will damage your i variable:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    char n_string[5];
    int i = 17;

    printf("Please enter your first name: ");
    scanf("%s", n_string);
    printf("\nYour name is: %s", n_string);
    printf("\nThe variable i is %d", i);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think there just happens to be valid memory in your process at the address contiguous to your array that means it just happens to work. However, it will be corrupting other memory elsewhere in the process by overwriting it.

Essentially you have a buffer overflow.